# How to Throttle DataStage

Tags: performance, resources, large-data-volumes, throttling, datastage

I work on a project where we run a number of DataStage sequences can be run in parallel, one in particular is poorly performing and takes a lot of resources, impacting the shared environment. Performance tuning initiative is in progress but will take time.

In the meantime I was hopeful that we could throttle DataStage to restrict the resources that could be used by this particular job/sequence - however I'm not personally experienced with DataStage specifically.

Can anyone comment if this facility exists in DataStage (v8.5 I believe), and point me in the direction of some further detail.

Secondly, I know that we can at the  throttle based on the user (I think this ties into AIX 'ulimit', but not sure). Is it easy/possbile to run different jobs/sequences as different users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this type of situations resources for a particular job can be restricted by specifying number of nodes and resources in  a config file. Possible in 8.5 and you may find something at [www.datastagetips.com](http://www.datastagetips.com)

Answer (score 1):

Revolution_In_Progress is right.

Datastage PX has the notion of a configuration file. That file can be specified for all the jobs you run or it can be overridden on a job by job basis. The configuration file can be used to limit the physical resources that are associated with a job.

In this case, if you have a 4-node config file for most of your jobs, you may want to write a 2-node config file for the job with performance issue. That way, you'll get the minimum amount of parallelism (without going completely sequential) and use the minimum amount of resources.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.tut.doc/module5/lesson5.1exploringtheconfigurationfile.html

Answer (score 0):

Sequence is a collection of individual jobs.

```
In most cases, jobs in a sequence can be rearranged to run serially.  Please check the organisation of the sequence and do a critical path analyis to remove the jobs that need not run in parallel to critical jobs.
```